# soapui and expected results in XQuery expression

Tags: xml, xquery, soapui

An excerpt of an XML:

```
   <ns4:Meldingen>                        
            <ns4:MeldingKey>
               <ns4:Nummer></ns4:Nummer>
               <ns4:Locale></ns4:Locale>
               <ns4:Kanaal></ns4:Kanaal>
               <ns4:Severity>Error</ns4:Severity>
               <ns4:Argumenten>
                  <ns4:Argument></ns4:Argument>
               </ns4:Argumenten>
               <ns4:Module></ns4:Module>
               <ns4:Routine></ns4:Routine>
            </ns4:MeldingKey>
    </ns4:Meldingen>
```

XQuery script for returning data :

```
<Result>
{
  for $x in //Meldingen/MeldingKey
   return<Severity>{data($x/Severity/text())}</Severity>
}
</Result>
```

My Expected results is more than one match:

```
   <Result>
     <Severity>Succes</Severity>
   </Result>

   <Result>
     <Severity>SuccesWithErrors</Severity>
   </Result>
```

The problem i am facing is that XQuery can only return one value of severity at the same time. Is it possible in soapui to assert on the 2 possible severities. So if XQuery returns Succes or SuccesWithErrors than the expectation is met otherwise it fails.

Comment: what is your question? what were your previous results with your xquery?

Comment: Still not sure what the question is here that can be answered. Do you mean you want to determine _whether_ any of those pieces of text are matched? If so, what do you want returned?

Comment: The most obvious problem here, by the way, is that you're checking `for $z in Meldingen/MeldingKey/Severity/text()`, but should perhaps be iterating over `for $z in ns4:Meldingen/ns4:MeldingKey/ns4:Severity/text()` (unless your XQuery processor implicitly converts it to `*:Meldingen/*:MeldingKey/*:Severity/text()`... which older versions of BaseX did, but new ones do not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me is that i changed the XQuery script that return a general result:

```
<Result>
{
for $x in //Meldingen/MeldingKey
where $x/Severity/text()='Succes' or $x/Severity/text()='SuccesWithErrors'  
return<Severity>Succes or SuccesWithErrors as result</Severity>

}
</Result>
```

and my expected result is this:

```
   <Result>
      <Severity>Succes or SuccesWithErrors as result</Severity>
   </Result>
```

If there is a match than the lights go green and i know then for sure that the severity is one of the two expectations. If the XQuery returns something else there is no match and the lights go red.